# ICU timezone data update in RHEL 8

Tags: php, linux, centos, redhat, icu

I have a RHEL 8.7 server that I need to update the ICU timezone data because mexico's now doesn't do DST. As far as I know it has ICU 60.3, i've been reading all the info I can and haven't been able to find something specific to how to update ICU.

I need to update ICU because im using PHP's intldateformatter function, and that function uses ICU. All the other TZ info i've updated successfully with the tzdata update.

Thanks!!

Comment: You either need a new build that was bundled with the updated tzdb, or https://pecl.php.net/package/timezonedb

Comment: Thanks, but using PECL's timezonedb doesn't works

Comment: What is the result of `var_dump(timezone_version_get())`?

Comment: Also, because I just stumbled over this in my local test, remember that `pecl install x` does not _enable_ `x`, you need to add the relevant config directive yourself.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 different time libraries that are used. PHP itself (and the built-in functions like `DateTime` and `DateTimezone`) use `timelib`. The ICU INTL library uses it's own built-in time library which includes it's own separate copy of the timezone db with a different format. Have a look here and follow the steps to download and copy the generated files from the github repository: https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/datetime/timezone/#icu4c-tz-update-when-icu-data-is-built-into-a-shared-library

1. Download the .txt file sources for the updated resources from https://github.com/unicode-org/icu-data/tree/main/tzdata/icunew/<IANA tz version>/44/le/

(Replace `<IANA tz version>` with the latest available in the repository. Going to the auto-generated link above will show a list of all available versions. You can pick the latest one by year and version letter. I put `/le/` at the end for little endian and is what most regular servers would use. If you need big endian or mainframe, replace it with the appropriate directory.)

3. Copy the downloaded .res files to any directory that is readable by the PHP / web server user.
4. Set the environment variable (to do it system-wide you can modify /etc/environment as a root user):
   ICU_TIMEZONE_FILES_DIR=/path/to/icu/tzdata/res/files

After setting the environment variable to the path where you copied the files (and exporting if needed), restart the web server and PHP (if running FPM or another process manager). The ICU/INTL extension should now be using the latest `timezonedb` data.

You can check the timezonedb version being used by ICU/INTL by using `phpinfo()` and searching for the INTL section.