# PHP 8.2: Unknown Timezone "America/Ciudad_Juarez" in IntlDateFormatter()

Tags: php, timezone, intl

I get in PHP 8.2 a error in [IntlDateFormatter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter) if I use "[America/Ciudad_Juarez](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.america.php)" as timezone:

> datefmt_create: No such time zone: 'America/Ciudad_Juarez':
> U_ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT_ERROR

Does anyone know the problem and how best to deal with it if a value from timezone_identifiers_list() cannot be processed in IntlDateFormatter()?

Comment: The `America/Ciudad_Juarez` timezone was added in ICU's 2022g timezone database version: https://data.iana.org/time-zones/tzdb/NEWS
The INTL extension uses ICU's own timezone database which is separate from what the built-in PHP functions use.
If you are using a version of PHP that includes an older INTL version, you need to update. You can do a `phpinfo()` to check which version of ICU and the TZDB is installed.

Comment: How do I update it? TZData is 2019a and ICU version is 60.3 on my AlmaLinux 8.9 and TZData not exists on Windows 11 in phpinfo().

Comment: The easiest way is to update your PHP version. Newer ICU & TZDB versions are included in newer PHP versions. PHP version 8 just went EOL today: https://endoflife.date/php You should be running 8.1 or newer.

Comment: I use PHP 8.2.12, so I don't think only newest version of PHP helps.

Comment: I don't see how you would have such an old INTL extension installed. Did you install PHP overtop of old install without updating the INTL extension?

Comment: My webhoster said they use ICU provided by the OS maintainers and currently AlmaLinux 8.9 use version ICU 60.3.

Comment: Ouch. I would ask them if there is any way to update it or install and use a custom version. If not, you're likely stuck.

Comment: I have installed PECL timezonedb version "2023.4" https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.timezone-version-get.php But this not help me yet. So I still searching for a solution. :)

Comment: The PECL package only affects PHP's internal date manipulation, not libicu that the INTL extension uses. The only way to get INTL's timezone database to be updated is to have libicu's timezone files updated. Your webhost would need to download, point ICU to the new tzdb files, and restart their servers. I answered another question with a basic tutorial here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76468967/icu-timezone-data-update-in-rhel-8/76469304#76469304

Answer (score -2):

The error occurs when you use a timezone that is not recognized by the IntlDateFormatter class.

Check the list of valid timezones using the timezone_identifiers_list function.

```
print_r(timezone_identifiers_list());
```

If you need to use a timezone that is not supported by the IntlDateFormatter function, you can try using the DateTime class.

```
$timezone = new DateTimeZone('America/Ciudad_Juarez');
$date = new DateTime('now', $timezone);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Sorry google translate :)

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, but I search a solution, not a workaround and this is in my case not practicable, because format() in IntlDateFormatter und DateTime is different syntax. I have IntlDateFormatter in a function that I call up a hundred times and have to change everywhere.